# How to resolve: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

Tags: java

Line InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream (con.getInputStream ()); returns this "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format" exception. Does anyone know how to solve this?

**my code:**

```
private String getJsonFromRapidAPI(final String url) throws Exception {

        final String token = generateSessionToken();
        final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        String fileContents = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = null;

        if (inetAddress == null) {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        }

        final String serverIP = inetAddress.getHostAddress();

        URL urlToCall = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlToCall.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
        con.setRequestProperty("Customer-Ip", serverIP);
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");

        InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream());

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");

        return writer.toString();

    }
```

Comment: Have you inspected what the inputstream from con.getInputStream() looks like?

Comment: Just because you mark the request with accept encoding gzip, that does not imply the server will always send back as gzip.

Comment: @DuncG i tried to add gzip, deflate, br but it doesn't work again

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here:

- You can tell a server you want GZIP encoding. That doesn't mean it'll neccessarily comply.

As a consequence, your current code goes: Well, I *asked* for gzip, so I will assume i Must gunzip the stream. That's incorrect - you need to ask for gzip as you do, but you need to let 'should I GZipInputStream the response' depend on whether **the server** actually did that. To figure this out, use `con.connect` to actually connect (`.getInputStream` implies it, but now we need to fetch some response info *before* opening the inputstream so you need to explicitly connect now), and you can call `."gzip".equals(con.getContentEncoding())` to figure it out. If that is `true`, then wrap `con.getInputStream()` in GZIPInputStream. If it isn't, don't do that.

- More generally you're abusing HttpURLConnection.

HttpURLConnection's job is to deal with the stream/processing of the data itself. That means headers like `Transfer-Encoding`, `Host`, and `Accept-Encoding` aren't 'your turf', you shouldn't be messing with this stuff. *It* needs to send 'hey, I can support gzip!' and *it* needs to wrap the response in a GZIPInputStream if the server says: "Great, okay, therefore I gzipped it for you!".

Unfortunately HttpURLConnection is extremely basic *and* messes up this distinction itself, for example it looks at the Transfer-Encoding header you set and will chunk sends (I think - oof, I haven't used this class in forever because its so bad).

If you have needs to make things even slightly complicated (and I'd say this qualifies), then stop using it. There's [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) from square. Java itself (Available in JDK11 and up, I think) [calls HttpURLConnection obsolete and has replaced it - here is a tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client), and even apache has [HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org) but note that this is outdated and as with most apache java libraries, oof, it's bad API design. I wouldn't use that one, even if it is rather popular. It's still much better than HttpURLConnection though!